# SQL Explain plan using J2EE for Informix

Tags: jakarta-ee, informix

Generating a SQL explain and retrieving it for every query is difficult for me on the work server. Is there a way I can have java code that executes a query as well as gives a SQL explain plan so that I can get all the data at once?

**Note:-**

 I'm using Informix database.

Comment: If you can access files on the machine where the Informix DBMS is running, then you can turn on the SET EXPLAIN statement, optionally choosing the file name, and then read the results from the file.  If you can't access files on that machine, then you're probably snookered.  The Informix server generates the query plan file on the machine where it's running.

Comment: If you are using informix 12.10 series, you can try the following functions: ifx_explain() and bson_explain(). The argument is the string representing the query.

Comment: @LuísMarques Can you put your comment as an answer. So I can accept it and give credit to you.

Comment: @daemon54 I have posted the information in my comment has an answer. Also posted the examples on the mentioned article, since it is no longer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Informix 12.10.XC2 forward you also have the possibility of using 2 new functions to retrieve the query plan:

- ifx_explain()
- bson_explain()

Unlike `EXPLAIN`, these functions never execute the query so they do not provide a Query Statistics section in the explain output ( [EXPLAIN_STAT configuration parameter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0081.htm) ).

These functions are not documented, but are mentioned in [How to acquire the Optimizer Explain File for a SQL statement into an Application.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160402074521/http://www.ibmnosql.com:80/2014/03/optimizer-explain-file/), now found via the Internet Archive Wayback Machine.

Using the examples provided in the link previously mentioned, in a local virtual machine with Informix installed I get the following:

```
execute function ifx_explain( 'select * from systables' );
(expression)
              QUERY: (OPTIMIZATION TIMESTAMP: 07-05-2019 16:57:42)
              ------
              select * from systables

              Estimated Cost: 11
              Estimated # of Rows Returned: 87

                1) informix.systables: SEQUENTIAL SCAN

--
-- bson_explain returns a BSON column, so cast it to a JSON, for human readability
--
SELECT bson_explain( 'select * from systables where tabid=99' )::JSON from sysmaster:sysdual

(expression)  {"version":1,"explain":"
              QUERY: (OPTIMIZATION TIMESTAMP: 07-05-2019 17:02:00)
              ------
              select * from systables where tabid=99

              Estimated Cost: 1
              Estimated # of Rows Returned: 1

                1) informix.systables: INDEX PATH

                  (1) Index Name: informix.tabid
                      Index Keys: tabid
                      Lower Index Filter: informix.systables.tabid = 99

              "}
```

Answer (score 0):

is ifx_explain an undocumented function ?
i can't find it in the documentation http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/search/ifx_explain?scope=SSGU8G_12.1.0&lang=en

Comment: It is undocumented. It is mentioned in this article: [www.ibmnosql.com/2014/03/optimizer-explain-file](http://www.ibmnosql.com/2014/03/optimizer-explain-file/)